# Is there any way to make angular re-render the view while having change detection detached for that specific component

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a big list which is rendered. I don't want angular change detector to check it's every value. I am looking for some way to ask angular to re-render with new values without checking previous values. Basically I want to have change detection detached all the time and re-render without re-attaching it. is this possible ?

I have tried everything with ChangeDetectorRef and in every case it still checks previous values before updating.

`<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">
   <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of proxyVar" >{{item.value}}</div>
 </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>`

Answer (score 0):

use an *ngIf condition in the html tag with a sentinel value that can be evaluated in the onChange to make sure your conditions are met before the view is refreshed

Comment: I have edited my post and added some code, could you tell me where you meant to add *ngIf to have my list visible all the time but not checked by angular change detection ?